# Git action not creating gh-pages branch

Tags: flutter, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my flutter app on github pages.
I've launched it locally with no issues, but the same can't be said for deploying it on github pages.

Im following the approach mentioned on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yQ27SSnWzk) which uses this [repo](https://github.com/bluefireteam/flutter-gh-pages), and following it, the gh-pages branch was not created for some reason. As such, I left main as the branch specified in build and deployment in hopes it would still work. This did not because index.html is not on root of main, and as such all I got was the error:

```
404

File not found

The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.

If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.
```

From the root of main, my flutter web app files are located in:

subdirectory_1/subdirectory_2/root_of_flutter_app/build/web/

The yml file i created by following the video and reading the instructions on the aforementioned repository is as follows:

```
name: Gh-Pages

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2 # Only works with v2
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      - uses: bluefireteam/flutter-gh-pages@v7
        with:
          workingDir: subdirectory_1/subdirectory_2/root_of_flutter_app/
          baseHref: /repo_name/
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not fluent enough in these matters to help you with just the info you've provided, but I have struggled with the same thing a tiny bit and I've made it working, so maybe by just having a look at my settings you will be able to figure out what is wrong.

Repo: https://github.com/GenixPL/portfolio5

[image]